# Print specific element from JavaScript array to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am a javascript noob and I am trying to create a sudoku generator and i want to print the array values into a table i made.
Here is the javascript code

```
function generateSudoku() {
    let grid = [    
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ];
    
  
    function isValid(grid, row, col, num) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (grid[row][i] == num || grid[i][col] == num) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      let boxX = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
      let boxY = Math.floor(col / 3) * 3;
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          if (grid[boxX + i][boxY + j] == num) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  
    function fillGrid(grid) {
      for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
          if (grid[row][col] == 0) {
            for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
              if (isValid(grid, row, col, num)) {
                grid[row][col] = num;
                if (fillGrid(grid)) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  grid[row][col] = 0;
                }
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <title>Sudoku Puzzle</title>
    
</head>  

<script>
    // Call the generateSudoku function to generate the grid
    generateSudoku();
  </script>

<body>
  <h1>Sudoku Puzzle</h1>
  <p>Fill in the missing numbers in the puzzle to make each row, column, and 3x3 subgrid contain the numbers 1 through 9 without repetition.</p>

  

  <table>
    
    <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-up"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
        <td class="subgrid-boundary-right subgrid-boundary-down"></td>
      </tr>
    <!-- Repeat for the remaining rows -->
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 50px auto;
    }
    
    td {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .subgrid-boundary-right {
      border-right: 3px solid black;
    }

    .subgrid-boundary-left {
      border-left: 3px solid black;
    }

    .subgrid-boundary-up {
      border-top: 3px solid black;
    }

    .subgrid-boundary-down {
      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    }
```

So i am wondering, how do I get the values from the GRID array to each go into the td lines.

I have tried a few things but in all honesty I do not understand why nothing will print and as a final attempt I want to see if someone here knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To display your generatedSudoku() in the HTML table, you need to use forEach() on the grid array, and then insert the values in the matched cells.

You can do so by adding this just after the `grid`:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("table tr").forEach((tr, row) => {
    tr.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((td, col) => {
      td.innerHTML = grid[row][col];
    });
  });
```

You should also call the function with onload of the page...

```
window.onload = function() {
  generateSudoku();
```

Comment: how do i insert the values into my td cells?

Comment: i just added this line and it didn't print anything into my grid
<td class="subgrid-boundary-left subgrid-boundary-up" id="grid[0][0]"></td>

Comment: did the ```window.onload = function() {generateSudoku()}``` worked on your side ?